# Get ng-model in ng-repeat with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, bdd, end-to-end

How can I get the ng-model in ng-repeat with protractor ?

```
<div ng-repeat="field in master.linker | orderBy:'country.name'">
    <div>
        <p> {{ field.country_name }} </p>
        <input ng-model="field.text">
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this, but without success :

```
var result = element.all(by.repeater('field in master.linker').column('field.text'));

result.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

I would like to compare :

```
result.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.country_name === 'en') {       
        expect(entry.text (from ng-repeat)).to.eventually.equal(value)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The `.column()` would only work for `binding`s, not the `model`s.**

In your case, use the [`by.model()` locator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model):

```
var result = element.all(by.repeater('field in master.linker'));

result.each(function(entry) {
    var input = entry.element(by.model("field.text"));

    // do smth with the input
});
```

If you want to get the input values, use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var inputValues = result.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.element(by.model("field.text")).getAttribute("value");
});

// printing out input values
inputValues.then(function (values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

---

Answering additional question from a comment:

> I have an array, without other fields from my ng-repeat, how can I compare "if (field.country_name === ""en") { expect(field.text).to.eventually.equal(value)}" ?

Use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var fields = element.all(by.repeater('field in master.linker'));
fields.filter(function (field) {
    return field.element(by.binding("field.country_name")).getText().then(function (country) {
        return country === "en";
    });
}).then(function (filteredFields) {
     var input = filteredFields[0].element(by.model("field.text"));
     expect(input.getAttribute("value")).to.eventually.equal(value);
});;
```

Comment: I have an object ptor : { ptor_: 
   { controlFlow: [Function],

Comment: @JérémieChazelle if you are trying to print out `input`, sure - you'll get that since this is an `ElementFinder` instance. What is your desired output? The values of the inputs? Thanks.

Comment: I have an array, without other fields from my ng-repeat, how can I compare "if (field.country_name === ""en") { expect(field.text).to.eventually.equal(value)}" ?

Comment: @JérémieChazelle okay, updated the answer, hope that helps.